# I need plus or minus icon set in accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I need plus or minus icon set in accordion. set plus or minus icon but icon not properly work.  when i open other tab not set icon or plus to minus or minus icon to plus icon set.

```
jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ankit8393/8kmdb2ks/5/
```

Comment: When you got the message that a JSFiddle link is not enough and you must copy-paste the code in the question, why didn't you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css:

```
.icon:after {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 3.5px;
  z-index: 4;
  content: "";
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {

    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
 var ii = $(this).find('.icon');

 $('.icon').not(ii).addClass('icon-plus');
  ii.toggleClass('icon-plus');

    //Hide the other panels
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w1bzvrex/1/

Comment: Not proper work. when click on tab multiple time not change icon.